# Git Rebased : shows Rebase 2/1 and some commit is not found

Tags: git

**(new_branch|REBASE 2/1)**

```
$git rebase --skip
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
error: Could not read 9d6ed2d2594e0c9f2e8ef0560b2dda0405c67070
fatal: bad tree object 9d6ed2d2594e0c9f2e8ef0560b2dda0405c67070
error: failed to run repack
```

how does it appear as REBASE 2/1... ??

Does anyone know the reason or have experienced this error previously ?

Comment: Rebasing is quite possibly the most interesting feature in Git, but unfortunately your question is not clear.

Comment: (new_branch|REBASE 2/1) --- have u experienced this ??  we usually find REBASE 1/2 ........ How does it appear as REBASE 2/1...  ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command `git rebase --quit` in your terminal, it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase --abort
```

this will abort the rebase activity and make a pull request again followed by merge or rebase.